The keys were thrown down a well. | "....thrown /into/in/down into a well.?"

The old keys were thrown down a well.

Beautiful country house history (See: 7:44-7:46)
For some reason, I can't make myself acquire the motor skill to use the preposition down in verbs of movements such as throw. Instead, I tend to remember other more obvious prepositions (to/in/into etc); for example thrown into a well occurs to me straight away rather than throw down a well
So, I wonder if I said thrown into/in a well, would it be incorrect?

Sidenote: "make myself acquire the motor skill..." how do you mean?

@Kaia, I mean, if I need to use the verb "throw something", the first prepositions that occur to my mind are usually "to/in/into/onto" but never "down". And I get angry with myself, why is it that I still can't get my mind to automatically remember that I need to use "down", when it is vertical structures like "well, sink, hole, etc"

ah gotcha. motor skill would really only be used for physical movements, like if you had a really hard time pronouncing "down", or if you had a hard time with physically throwing a key down a well. Something like "presence of mind" or "mental dexterity" might be the equivalent for "remembering the right preposition". Or just "I can never remember to use..."

throw down on the ground/throw up in the toilet/throw a towel around your body/throw x through the window/ etc. This is English. You just have to get used to it. "down a well" is a perfectly acceptable prepositional phrase.

@Lambie, Really interesting examples for us, non-native speakers. Yes, I will continue to learn and get used to them.

In an examination the answer will be marked wrong -  The old keys were thrown in a well     I "in" cannot be used because there's change of position of the object (keys). https://clapingo.com/blog/in-vs-into


throw keys [something] down, into or in a well [a place].

Also, therefore: throw keys down into the well. intensifies the statement.
Those are all acceptable prepositional phrases.
The old keys were thrown down a well.
Wells are known for depth, so down is fine. Like stairs or a hole: Throw keys down the stairs, down a deep hole.
down, into and in have slightly different emphases in this phrase.
If you are standing at the rim (wall) of the well, into or down are very evocative. But in is ok too. down marks the fact a well stretches downwards. Into marks the fact of the well being like a container. And in is just good ole in.

Please disregard the downvote. :)

For @Yunus: This touches on what would have been my response: These words can group together in different ways as phrases. "Down [a] well" is a common pairing, e.g. "fallen down a well." Don't worry about the relationship between "throw" and "down"; it could just have easily have been a different verb, or a different preposition if was thrown somewhere else. (Meanwhile, "throw down" is a completely unrelated red herring that we won't talk about...)

@AndyBonner Just give your own answer. Don't piggyback on mine. Thanks.

Sorry; I just had so little else to add that I thought it didn't merit a separate answer. Upvoted too since you said what I would have.

Not explicitly stated, but the example with stairs is of course not entirely parallel to wells and holes: since stairs are not deep or containers, you can throw your keys something down the stairs, but not *in(to) the stairs.

@JanusBahsJacquet I was careful not to say that.

@JanusBahsJacquet you could throw them into the stairwell of some buildings though! "Into" or "down" the stairwell would suggest they fell straight down the middle with the stairs around them, while "down the stairs" suggests they hit the actual steps, at leats at the bottom

"Down" carries an implication that they fell a long way, much more so than "into".  Consider "the old keys were thrown down/into a well but they snagged on a stone at the top"  - "down" doesn't make much sense there, unlike "into"

"Thrown into a well" is fine. "Thrown in a well" is OK, but less natural.
The rule of thumb for in vs into is that in is for location and into is for change and movement.

I go into the hospital.
(OK, LESS NATURAL) I go in the hospital.
I am in the hospital.
(INCORRECT) I am into the hospital. (This would idiomatically mean "I'm interested in the hospital.")

Since throw is a movement, into is better. (In is usable sometimes. I'd say "throw that in the trash," for instance.)

As a secondary concern, if you're storing an item, I think in gives the sense of putting something in a convenient location for later, and into implies that it's been moved somewhere and will have to be moved back out later.

I put it in a bowl.
I put it into the storage unit.

Since throwing a key in a well makes it hard to retrieve, into makes more sense. If you were hiding the key someplace to retrieve it later, you'd say:

I hid the key in the well.


OP's query:

The old keys were thrown down a well."
So, I wonder if I said "...thrown into/in a well...", would it be incorrect?

Down' performs many functions in English. It can be a noun, a verb, an adjective, an adverb, and a preposition..
Adverb examples - lie down, sat down, is down, going down, turn down
Phrasal verb: Down combines with a verb to form a phrasal verb or a verb phrase, often changing its meaning.
write down (record), put down (place or stop), take down (remove or note), turn down (reduce or decline),
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

in or towards a low or lower position, from a higher one:
I slid down the hill.
fall down Aikiko fell down some stairs and broke her wrist.

In OP's case "in" is not used because there's change of position of the object (keys).
The sentence can be conveyed in the following ways:
1. The old keys were thrown down a well. (shows direction).
2. The old keys were thrown into a well. (shows entry)..
3. The old keys were thrown down into a well.
Edit -1.
Mistake of using "in".
One widespread mistake involves using 'in' when the action signifies movement or direction, requiring 'into'. For instance, incorrectly saying "He jumped in the pool" instead of the correct "He jumped into the pool". Here 'into' signifies moving from outside to inside..
https://clapingo.com/blog/in-vs-into.
